# Alert on different platforms based on condition

Tags: alert, datadog

How can we alert on different platforms like Slack and PagerDuty based on a condition (say environment)?

Below is how my query on a log monitor looks like:

```
index:main source:(xxx OR yyyy) @level:emergency @vulnerability.log_type:(aaa OR xxx) @vulnerability.type:image_scan
```

Grouping this by environment, I wanted to move produdction related alerts to PagerDuty and others to Slack or mail to a group.

I tried this and it seems to be working, but I want to explore other options.

```
{^is_match 'environment.name' '*nonprod'}} @slack-test {{/is_match}}

{{^is_match 'environment.name' 'prod'}} @abc@xxx.com {{/is_match}}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: {{^ is_match}} didnt work for me, however {{#is_exact_match}} did the job